# How to get TouchEvent in touchPad of laptop in Qt environment?

Tags: qt, touch-event, touchpad

I want to get TouchEvent of touchPad of Laptop in Qt program. but in the program below, I can't get the TouchEvent. For help, thank you.

```
bool MyDialog::event(QEvent *evt)
{
    qDebug()<<evt->type();//can't get the touchEvent
    …
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents` attribute set on `MyDialog`?

Comment: Yes, I have set the attribute, but it doesn't work. My os is windows 7,and IDE is Qt creator 3.2.1

Comment: Do you get mouse events, or nothing, instead of touch events?

Comment: yes, I get mouseEvents, including mouve/press and so on. But how can I get TouchEvent? thank  you

Comment: No, I meant do you get mouse events _instead of_ touch events when you press the touch pad?

Comment: Yes, but how can I get the TouchEvent type? Thank you.

Comment: I can get MouseEvent, but not TouchEvent. could you help me? @cmannett85